# Does the Flame Blade spell count as a melee weapon that can be used with the paladin's Divine Smite feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, weapons, paladin

With the release of the new [*Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/motm/fantastical-races#FireGenasiTraits), the revamped [Fire Genasi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1026388-fire-genasi#FireGenasiTraits) trait "Reach to the Blaze" now allows the race access to the *flame blade* spell:

> [...] Starting at 5th level, you can also cast the *flame blade* spell with this trait, without a material component. [...]

This made me think, if *flame blade* can be used with the paladin's Divine Smite feature, casting *flame blade* at 5th level with Divine Smite using a 5th-level spell slot will result in 4d6 fire damage and at least 5d8 radiant damage.

**Does *flame blade* count as a melee weapon that can be used with Divine Smite?**

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Slight aside but at 5th level the Paladin is just getting access to level 2 spell slots (different classes get spells at different rates so it isn't directly proportional to the level of the character) so you'd be looking at 3d8 radiant damage from a second level divine smite and 3d6 from the flame blade.

Comment: The answer was no anyways, but the idea was that the character would have access to 2 5th level spell slots to do this which would be I think a level 12, with 2 levels in paladin and 10 levels in wizard. The fifth level thing was just when you start to get access with the flame blade.

Answer (score 20):

### No

Generally, *flame blade* is not considered a weapon and so doesn't work with spells and features which require one, such as [green flame blade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129842/52137) or [opportunity attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80686/52137).

For Divine Smite though there's an even more clear cut issue. *Flame blade* has you make a spell attack (emphasis added):

> You can use your action to make a melee *spell attack* with the fiery blade.

and Divine Smite requires a weapon attack:

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a melee *weapon attack*, you can expend one spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target, in addition to the weapon’s damage.

Thus this doesn't work without a DM overriding it (which is quite possible for *flame blade*).